# How to structure my Django web scraping project?

Tags: python, django, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm fairly new to programming and still have some issues structuring my projects in Django.
I'm setting up a web scraper application and my goal is to visualize the scraped data and return it in different kinds of diagrams.

At the moment I've the scraping code in the views.py file.

My question is: Is there a preferred directory structure for this kind of applications?

I was thinking about:

-setting up the scraping code in a new scrape.py

-setting up models to feed the data to in models.py

-setting up the visualization code in the views.py

This is my views.py atm :

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def PlayerDetailView(request):

    first_name = 'Drew'
    last_name = 'Brees'
    last_name_first_letter = last_name[0]
    last_name_first_four = last_name[0:4]
    first_name_first_two = first_name[0:2]


    page = requests.get('https://www.pro-football-reference.com/players/{}/{}{}00.htm'.format(last_name_first_letter,                                                                                            last_name_first_four,                                                                                                                                first_name_first_two))


    content = page.content

    week_number = 251
    stats = soup.find("tr", {"id": "stats.{}".format(week_number)})

    stats_relevant = ['pass_yds', 'pass_td', 'rush_yds']
    stat_list = []


for stat in stats_relevant:
    stat_list.append(int(list(stats.find("td", {"data-stat": "{}".format(stat)}).children)[0]))

dic_list = {'tag':stat_list}
    return render(request,'league_app/player.html', context=dic_list)
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been recently working on a web scraping project in Flask and serving the scraping functions as a callable API through Flask. This way I am able to easily test the API and functions through `curl` calls or a simple front-end with a handful of JavaScript, depending on your preferences.

So, in the above case we could have:

- Scraping functions in "scraping.py"
- Server (Django or Flask) code in "controller.py"
- Database or data structure code in "models.py"
- (Optional) Web site code in related HTML, CSS, and JavaScript files

Once a few functions have been routed to URI's, you can start up the server by calling the "controller.py" file and make API calls like:

```
curl -o output.json http://localhost:5000/getjson
```

I would look more into the power of `curl`, especially for rapid development purposes. Personally, I found a wealth of information over at https://docs.python-guide.org/ in regards to proper program structuring. It goes into a lot of detail on pretty much everything you can think of. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

First create your data model to save your scraped data,
Then use a task queue using [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) to scrape data and then store it in your database.
Visualize your data using the data in your database.